# HTML 'Title' attribute showing the word 'undefined' - eg. 'Home Pageundefined'

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash

I am currently having an issue with my Web site 'title'. This is currently showing incorrect, as 'Kush Koutureundefined', where this should display 'Kush Kouture' (please see link to screenshot - http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/38/screenshotnpe.jpg/).

My Web site consists of a .swf (index.swf) embeded into the index.html

here is my code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<meta name="author" content="Kush Kouture" /> 
<meta name="keywords" content="Kush Kouture" /> 
<meta name="description" content="Kush Kouture" /> 

<title>Kush Kouture</title> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfaddress.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="swffit.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var flashvars = {}; 
flashvars.url_config = "xml/configuration_site.xml"; 
flashvars.initServices = true; 
var params = {}; 
params.allowfullscreen = true; 
params.allowScriptAccess = "always"; 
var attributes = {}; 
attributes.id = 'flashObject'; 
attributes.bgcolor = '#000000'; 

swfobject.embedSWF("flash/index.swf", "Alternative", "100%", "100%", "8", "flash/index.swf", flashvars, params, attributes); 
</script> 

<style type="text/css"> 
/* hide from ie on mac \*/ 
html { 
height: 100%; 
overflow: hidden; 
} 

#flashcontent { 
height: 100%; 
} 
/* end hide */ 

body { 
height: 100%; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
background-color: #ffffff; 
} 
p { 

font-size: 10px; 
font-family: Verdana; 
line-height:17px; 
color:#ffffff; 

}  
.style1 { 
font-size: 11px; 
font-family: Verdana; 
color:#ffffff; 
text-transform:uppercase; 
} 
</style> 

</head> 
<body> 

<div id="flashContent> 
<object id="flashObject" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=11,0,0,0" width="100%" height="100%"> 
<param name="movie" value="flash/index.swf" /> 
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" /> 
<param name="width" value="100%" /> 
<param name="height" value="100%" /> 
<param name="scale" value="noscale" /> 
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flash/index.swf" align=""      scale="noscale" wmode="transparent" width="100%" height="100%"> 
</object> 
</object> 
</div> 

<div id="Alternative">  
<p style="color:#999999">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Kush Kouture | You require the latest version of Adobe Flash Player in order to view this site. Please use the button below to download the latest version.</p> 
<p><a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/"><img src="flash.jpg" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p> 
</div> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what extension does the file have? Have you tried in other browsers? Why not post an online demo?

Comment: He means the title should be 'Kush Kouture' instead of 'Kush Koutureundefined'.. Not very clear from the question indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it looks like something is altering (adding) to your current title tag. Could be the swf or maybe some js. I suggest you take out one component at a time to find out which file is doing it and go from there.

Comment: I have managed to resolve this issue as a few '"' were missing from the DOCTYPE.. I am still having issues with the embded .swf loading. My web site is www.kushkouture.com

Answer (score 2):

Seems you can alter page titles from within Flash:

[Setting Page Title from a SWF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87909/setting-page-title-from-a-swf)

this would be my most likely candidate. Did you write the flash app?

Comment: Both of your solutions are fair workarounds (if they work indeed).. However it doesn't really solve the problem, and it might not work in all browsers or different browser versions... A bit tricky therefore.

Comment: your missing my point (not sure I explained as clearly bas I should), the HTML looks fine, nothing in there setting the title to anything none-standard so it looks to me like the SWF is altering the title.

Comment: Either that or the javascript.

Comment: yes or the Javascript, but looking at the js files your referencing, I'd say that's unlikely.

Comment: This site works in all browsers. I am currently taking a look at the .SWF, which I did create myself.

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/32039/having-an-issue-with-my-web-site-loading-this-is-a-swf-file-embedded-into-the